# How do I get the console output to write over the console rather than do plaintext output?

Tags: c++, c

**Edit: Here's the sequel to this question. [Drawing colors to console causes color flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438588/drawing-colors-to-console-causes-color-flicker)**

So, in C/C++ commands like `printf` and `cout` will write plaintext output. So a video game designed for a 80×25 text display and 60fps would have to output 2000 characters of text every frame. I would like to write over the screen, like a command that would, say, write a string to columns 4 to 9 on row 12 or something, rather than constantly appending plaintext each time something changes. I don't mean graphical output, this is still text mode, but not plaintext-embedded-in-console type of text mode.

Edit: For those wondering, code that outputs an entire screen of plaintext each frame of animation looks like this: https://github.com/PiotrGrochowski/testsortingvisualization/blob/master/test.cpp . It glitches out sometimes, and I haven't calculated the speed (whether it's 60fps or not).

Edit: The concept of the text display being a fixed 80×25 indeed does mean that there isn't any concept of scrolling or newlines.

Edit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode . How do I get this to the command prompt in C/C++ programming?

Comment: That's not possible in standard C++, you have to use OS-specific libraries.

Comment: Run a Google search for "curses library", and start reading. It is a fairly simplistic, rudimentary library that takes care of a bunch of low-level operating system details and presents an API for dynamic screen updates. Expect to spend a month or two learning how to use it. Like most complicated things in C++ there is no instant gratification, you will need to spend a little bit of time studying and learning how to use curses.

Comment: `write a string to columns 4 to 9 on row 12` - [Ansi escape codes - terminal output sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Terminal_output_sequences) - move the cursor to column 4 row 12 and output a character and repeat.

Comment: It's still plaintext!

Comment: "curses" is more of a Unix thing, but the link you posted was to a thing for MS Windows. However, there is an implementation called "PDCurses" that has a port to Windows.

Comment: ANSI escape codes are fine as long as supported (most Linux shells do since long), on Windows, you have support for not before Win10...

Comment: An approach similar to double buffering might bring some improvement, too (if you don't already do so anyway): Write all data into one large array, then output that one in one single go. Only one system call, only one transition from user to kernel space, etc... If you keep std::cout in [sync with C standard IO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio), you might lose a bit of performance as well.

Comment: If double buffering the contents of the terminal, then perform all the output during the screen retrace time.  This can (usually) be accomplished via hooking the appropriate interrupt event

Answer (score 3):

For simple operations, such as cursor position and text color, you can use ANSI escape codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Terminal_output_sequences
That will work if the console supports it, which is on Linux, Unix, Mac, and allegedly also in Windows 10.

An example is here: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Cursor_positioning#C.2FC.2B.2B

If the console supports ANSI escape codes, the following will print "Hello" on row 6, column 3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("\033[6;3HHello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

On Windows, when console does not support ANSI, there are Windows-specific functions:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD pos = {3, 6};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, pos);
    WriteConsole(hConsole, "Hello", 5, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

You can also use the ncurses library for POSIX.